# Cisco 861 - Unable to traceroute

Tags: cisco, router, ios

I'm having an issue with my Cisco 861. I'm unable to traceroute to any ip address from the router, even the next hop. Can anyone suggest possible causes.

Apologies for the censoring but I won't take a chance posting IP's online

```
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime show-timezone
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime show-timezone
no service password-encryption
!
hostname ####
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
logging buffered 51200 warnings
enable secret 5 ####
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 10
clock summer-time EST recurring
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1
!
ip dhcp pool vlan1pool
 import all
 network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.1.254 
 domain-name ####
 dns-server ### ###
 lease 14
!
!
ip inspect name fire-rules tcp
ip inspect name fire-rules udp
ip inspect name fire-rules ssh
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name ###
ip name-server ###
ip name-server ###
ip cef
!
!
password encryption aes
license udi pid CISCO861-K9 sn ###
!
!
username ### privilege 15 secret 5 ###
!
!
! 
!
crypto isakmp policy 2
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
crypto isakmp key 6 ####
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set cmevpn esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
!
!
!
crypto map ### 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 set peer ###
 set transform-set cmevpn 
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address ### 255.255.255.255
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address ### 255.255.255.252
 tunnel source ###
 tunnel destination ##
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 2
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet2
 no ip address
!         
interface FastEthernet3
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet4
 description ip
 ip address ##87 255.255.255.192
 ip access-group 150 in
 ip inspect fire-rules out
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
 crypto map cmevpn
!
interface Vlan1
 description 'Default Vlan'
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address ### 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
no ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip mroute ###.###.19.0 255.255.255.0 Tunnel0
ip nat inside source static tcp <Mail IP> 25 <Public IP> 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <DNS IP> 53 <Public IP> 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp <DNS IP> 53 <Public IP> 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <Mail IP> 443 <Public IP> 443 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp <Mail IP> 443 <Public IP> 443 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp <Mail IP> 993 <Public IP> 993 extendable
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.0 <Next Hop IP>
ip route ### 255.255.255.255 <Next Hop IP>
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit ip  ### ###
access-list 100 permit gre host ### host ###
access-list 150 permit udp any any eq isakmp
access-list 150 permit ahp any any
access-list 150 permit esp any any
access-list 150 permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list 150 permit tcp any host <Public IP> eq smtp
access-list 150 permit tcp any host <Public IP> eq domain
access-list 150 permit udp any host <Public IP> eq domain
access-list 150 permit tcp any host <Public IP> eq 443
access-list 150 permit udp any host <Public IP> eq 443
access-list 150 permit tcp any host <Public IP> eq 993
access-list 150 deny   tcp any any
access-list 150 deny   udp any any
access-list 150 deny   ip any any
no cdp run
!
line con 0
 login local
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 access-class 1 in
 privilege level 15
 login local
 transport input telnet ssh
!
ntp server 194.35.252.7 prefer
sntp server 194.35.252.7
sntp server 81.168.77.149
sntp server 194.164.127.6
sntp source-interface FastEthernet4
end
```

Comment: `I'm unable to traceroute to any ip address from the router` doesn't describe a problem that I would care too much about. Does the router forward/route traffic appropriately? That is a problem I would care about. My point being, is the inability to tracert a symptom of another problem?

Comment: Your problem description is very poor. What happens when you try? What goes wrong? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Apologies for the bad description. Let me colour the situation alittle. We are in serviced offices. The building gateway is the next hop. When I trace to Google nothing beyond the router appears. Whereas another sysadmin in the building is able to see what hops on a trace. At the end user I get a ttl exceeded message, I have upped the ttl but it still gets lost